# Raspberry PI 4: green led 4 long flash followed by 4 fast blinks

Tags: pi-4, boot, printing

Im trying to install octoklipper onto my Pi 4. I have a 32gb SD card and after the writing of octoklipper my sd card gets split into 3 partitions. one of three partitions is unallocated. I have tried 2 different sd cards both same result. when I insert the sd into the Pi i get 4 long flash then 4 fast flashes from the green led. Really scratching my head here.

Comment: What image are you using? Does it state compatibility with a Pi4?

Comment: Details please.  Has this Pi ever worked?  What have you changed?

Comment: That is a head-scratching sequence: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#led-warning-flash-codes